# Set MongoDB 2.6 log without restarting

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am trying to set a new log destination without restarting.

It is unclear to me what to set / how to set it.

I am running

```
localhost > db.version()
2.6.3
```

I want to change the system log to

```
/var/log/mongod/mongod_NA.log
```

I have  tried

```
localhost > db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, "systemLog": "/var/log/mongod/mongodb/mongod_NA.log" } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no option found to set, use help:true to see options "
}

localhost > db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, "Log": "/var/log/mongod/mongodb/mongod_NA.log" } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no option found to set, use help:true to see options "
}

localhost > db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, "logPath": "/var/log/mongod/mongodb/mongod_NA.log" } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no option found to set, use help:true to see options "
}

localhost > db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, help: true , systemLog: { 'path': '/var/log/mongod_NA.log' } } )
{
    "help" : "help for: setParameter set administrative option(s)\n{ setParameter:1, <param>:<value> }\nsupported:\n  [ ... ]",
    "lockType" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a MongoDB admin command to change the `systemLog` path. This is a startup option that has to be configured at the process level (`mongod` or `mongos`) and is typically set as one of the options in a MongoDB configuration file. You will need to restart your MongoDB service or process in order to change any startup options.

However, if your goal is to use a new log file because the current one has grown too large, you should look into the [`logRotate` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/logRotate/) and setting up regular log rotation in your environment (for example, using `logrotate` on Linux).

I assume you're also aware that MongoDB 2.6 is very outdated now (this release series reached end of life in Oct 2016). There are some [important stability and security fixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.6-changelog/) in subsequent releases, so at the very least you should try to upgrade to the final 2.6.12 release which is almost 2 years newer than 2.6.3. Minor releases like 2.6.x do not introduce any backward-breaking changes from earlier 2.6 releases.